# Efficient way to upload huge number of small files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip, video-streaming

I'm encoding dash streams locally that I intend to stream through Cloudfront after, but when it comes to uploading the whole folder it get counted as +4000 PUT requests. So, I thought instead to compress it and upload the zip folder that would count as only 1 PUT request, and then Unzip it using lambda.

My question is, is lambda still going to use the PUT requests for unzipping the file ? And if so, what would be a better/cost effective way to achieve this ?

Comment: No, Lambda will make 1 PUT request to download the file & then it will take X seconds/minutes to unzip the file -  efficiency will be based on how long it takes the unzip the file

Comment: So, the file gets uploaded on 'uploaded' bucket and then an event triggers the lambda function that unzips the file at another bucket called 'production'. In this case, do I only have the costs of lambda function and storage ? Or do I have PUT, COPY, POST, LIST as well calculated in the overall cost ? ps. the zip files contain +4000 files each

Comment: Any solution to upload 4000 files to S3, be it from your home PC, Lambda, EC2, or whatever, will require 4000 PUT requests to perform the operation.

Comment: @AnonCoward Not if he has zipped up the files, no it will not. It will class as 1 PUT request.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary from OP's comment eventually they need to put the individual files into a bucket. That's still going to take 1 PUT each.

Comment: @jingx Ah, the comment - yes, no way around that ofc.

Comment: Although, 1 million requests cost 5 cents. So I don't see how that's a cost concern.  I would imagine (and hope) when OP puts the streams online, the traffic cost will be way more than that. :-)

Comment: @jingx I agree with you, but since it's the beginning it's best to try to minimise whatever costs you can in order to make room for costs that will come up in the future. Thank you all for the replies.

Comment: ＠jingx It cost 5 USD per million put request

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way around having to pay for the individual PUT/POST requests per-file.

S3 is expensive.  So is anything related to video streaming.  The bandwidth and storage costs will eclipse your HTTP request costs.  You might consider a more affordable provider.  AWS is the highest price out of all that do S3-compatible hosting.

Comment: Any other suggestions for S3-compatible hosting ?

Comment: PS. Having a CDN where I can implement some authentication through signedCookies or other methods that would allow access to directories based on policies would be a plus..

Comment: @iSpark Digital Ocean Spaces is probably your best bet.  You can DIY this with Minio.  Backblaze has an offering as well, but it isn't intended for this sort of hosting and probably won't perform well.

Comment: with minio would require having a physical server, that I'm trying to avoid.. So, are you saying that Digital Ocean Spaces pretty much offers the same with a lower cost than AWS ?

Comment: I contacted them, perhaps I could get a better grasp of how it would work with them.. Thank you @Brad

Comment: @iSpark Minio does not require a physical server.  You can host Minio on any virtual hosting as well.  And yes, DigitalOcean Spaces is about half the cost of AWS S3.

Comment: @iSpark If it's helpful, here's my DigitalOcean referral code:  https://m.do.co/c/047e545d941f  Good for $100 off over 2 months.